# Problems Computing (in a reasonable amount of time) Solutions to a System of Inequalities

Tags: equation-solving

For my Cryptography research I am interested in finding solutions to the following inequalities in terms of $r$ and $s$, where $p$ is some fixed constant.

$$\begin{align}
2^{p - s + 4} + 2^{p - r} + 2^{p - r - s + 4} + 13/4 < 2^{p - 8} \\
2^{p - r + 4} + 2^{p - s + 8} + 2^{p - r - s + 8} + 13/4 < 2^{p - 4}
\end{align}$$

I have tried the following computation:

```
Solve[2^(p - s + 4) + 2^(p - r) + 2^(p - r - s + 4) + 13/4 < 2^(p - 8) && 
2^(p - r + 4) + 2^(p - s + 8) + 2^(p - r - s + 8) + 13/4 < 2^(p - 4), {r, s}]
```

Unfortunately, it is taking forever to compute (literally days), so does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using `Reduce[]` instead of `Solve[]`?

Comment: @J.M. I have not, I will go try it! Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Specify domain as an option `Reduce[... , {r,s} , Integers]` or `Solve[... , {r,s} , Reals]` - depending on what you are looking for. It may not be solvable. Try to narrow down parameter **P** then.

Comment: I tried both of your ideas and they were not very useful in reducing the computation time. Any other ideas?

Comment: Why a downvote ???  This question is  really good one, showing limits of symbolic computing (at least of Solve or Reduce). And it is really original among hundreds boring questions on front-end rubbish.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's start by seeing if there is a solution at all.

```
conds = 2^(p - s + 4) + 2^(p - r) + 2^(p - r - s + 4) + 13/4 < 2^(p - 8) &&
        2^(p - r + 4) + 2^(p - s + 8) + 2^(p - r - s + 8) + 13/4 < 2^(p - 4)
FindInstance[ conds, {p, r, s}, Integers]
(* {{p->84, r->164, s->92}} *)
```

Ok, that looks nice, there is at least one solution. We can visualize the solution space including the solution `FindInstance` found with

```
RegionPlot3D[conds, {p, 0, 200}, {r, 0, 200}, {s, 0, 200}, AxesLabel -> {p, r, s}]
```

[image: RegionPlot of solution space]

Ok, it looks there are hard lower limits for each parameter and a soft transition between those planes. We can have a look at that interesting part.

```
RegionPlot3D[conds, {p, 7, 20}, {r, 7, 20}, {s, 7, 20}, AxesLabel -> {p, r, s}]
```

[image: RegionPlot of solution space detail]

Now to get some quantifiable lower limits, we can make it easier for `Reduce` by working with 2 to the power of `p`,`r`,`s` instead of the parameters themselves.

```
powconds = conds /. Thread[{p, r, s} -> Log[2, {pp, pr, ps}]]
```

[image: conditions in terms of the powers]

`Reduce[powconds, {pp, pr, ps}, Integers]` still takes forever so let's constrain `pp`,`pr`,`ps` to be positive.

```
pospowconds = powconds && And @@ Thread[{pp, pr, ps} > 0]
```

[image: pow conditions with positive integer constraint]

Now

```
reducedconds = Reduce[pospowconds, {pp, pr, ps}]
```

is able to find a nice reduction

[image: reduced pow conditions]

that we can transform back to our original parameters

```
newconds = reducedconds /. Thread[{pp, pr, ps} -> 2^{p, r, s}]
```

[image: reduced conditions in the original parameters]

or in terms of `p`,`r`,`s` that is

```
newconds /. Greater[a_, b_] -> Greater[Log[2, a], Log[2, b]] // PowerExpand
```

[image: taking the logarithm of the inequalities]

So now we have a lower limit for `p`. Are there lower limits for `r` and `s`, too?
Let's go back to the reduced power conditions and ask the question in terms of quantifiers

```
questions =  MapThread[ 
    Exists[#1, ForAll[{pp, pr, ps}, reducedconds, #2 > #1]] &,
    {{lowerpr, lowerps}, {pr, ps}}
  ]
```

[image: Are there lower limits for r and s?]

and let Mathematica resolve the questions for us

```
Resolve /@ questions
(* {True, True} *)
```

So there are lower limits for `r` and `s`, too. Nice! Since we're lazy we let Mathematica do the work of finding the highest lower limit for which the conditions are still satisfied:

```
VariableGreaterThan[var_, threshold_] := Resolve[
    ForAll[{pp, pr, ps}, reducedconds, var > threshold]
  ]
lowerpowerlimits = FindMaxValue[
    {th, VariableGreaterThan[#, th] \[And] th \[Element] Integers},
    {th, 1}
  ] & /@ {pp, pr, ps}
(* 832., 256., 4096. *)
```

so the lower limits of `p`, `r`, `s` are

```
lowerlimits = Log[2, lowerpowerlimits]
(* {9.70044, 8., 12.} *)
```

Our plot of the solution space from above with the new tight bounds

```
RegionPlot3D[
    conds,
    {p, #1, #1 + 10}, {r, #2, #2 + 10}, {s, #3, #3 + 10}, 
    AxesLabel -> {p, r, s}
  ] & @@ lowerlimits
```

[image: solution space with tighter bounds]

Comment: Thank you very much for the thoughtful response, your answer was the most useful for actually answering my question so I am accepting it (although the other ones were also very insightful as well!)

Comment: Thanks for the positive feedback, glad that it was helpful to you!

Answer (score 9):

Just to clarify, you keep mentioning speed, but there is **no** issue with speed, but fundamental solvability. Both of this formulation will **almost momentarily** report about solvability impasse:

```
eq = 2^(p - s + 4) + 2^(p - r) + 2^(p - r - s + 4) + 13/4 < 
   2^(p - 8) && 2^(p - r + 4) + 2^(p - s + 8) + 2^(p - r - s + 8) + 13/4 < 
   2^(p - 4); eq // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
Solve[eq, {r, s}, Reals]
```

[image]

```
Reduce[eq, {r, s}, Reals]
```

[image]

So, to reiterate, this is not the issue of time, but solvability. You should always try to tweak your problem to make it solvable. For example set some numerical values for some parameters and see if solution makes sense. Following the **@belisarius** advice in the comments, try specific instances:

```
FindInstance[2^(p - s + 4) + 2^(p - r) + 2^(p - r - s + 4) + 13/4 < 2^(p - 8) && 
  2^(p - r + 4) + 2^(p - s + 8) + 2^(p - r - s + 8) + 13/4 < 
   2^(p - 4) && p == 256 && 0 < r <= s, {p, r, s}, Reals, 10]
```

[image]

Or Try visualization:

```
RegionPlot3D[eq, {p, 10, 15}, {r, 9, 10}, {s, 13, 15}, Mesh -> 8, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, Norm[{x, y, z}]]}, 
 MeshShading -> {Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.4]], FaceForm[Cyan, Red]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Try `FindInstance[
 2^(p - s + 4) + 2^(p - r) + 2^(p - r - s + 4) + 13/4 < 2^(p - 8) && 
  2^(p - r + 4) + 2^(p - s + 8) + 2^(p - r - s + 8) + 13/4 < 
   2^(p - 4) && p == 256 && 0 < r <= s, {p, r, s}, Reals, 10]
`

Comment: For some detail `RegionPlot3D[eq, {p, 10, 15}, {r, 8, 10}, {s, 12, 15}]`

Comment: @belisarius thanks, nice catch - I updated the post, gave you credit. Still there is no issue with time as author claims.

Comment: Yep. You are right

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov: Thanks for clearing up my concern about how I thought the computation was using a bad algorithm since it was taking so long to do.

Answer (score 9):

`FindInstance` may give us many solutions but no information on the solution space. So this is not a very welcome approach.  Therefore we would rather like bounds for `p,r,s`  working with `Reduce`.

We get rid of `2^p, 2^r, 2^s` changing them respectively to `x, y, z`.

```
ineq= 2^(p - s + 4) + 2^(p - r) + 2^(p - r - s + 4) + 13/4 < 2^(p - 8) && 
      2^(p - r + 4) + 2^(p - s + 8) + 2^(p - r - s + 8) + 13/4 < 2^(p - 4)

ineq1 = ineq /. Thread[ {p, r, s} -> Log2 @ {x, y, z}]
```

> ```
>  13/4 + x/y + (16 x)/z + (16 x)/(y z) < x/256 && 
>  13/4 + (16 x)/y + (256 x)/z + (256 x)/(y z) < x/16
> ```

and we solve the inequalities with respect to `y , z` assuming them to be real and positive :

```
Reduce[ ineq1 && y > 0 && z > 0 && x > 0, {y, z}, Reals]
```

> ```
>  x > 832 && y > (256 x)/(-832 + x) && z > (4096 x + 4096 x y)/(-256 x - 832 y + x y)
> ```

To proceed further we can do this

```
x > 832 && y > (256 x)/(-832 + x) &&
z > (4096 x + 4096 x y)/(-256 x - 832 y + x y) /. {x -> 2^p, y -> 2^r, z -> 2^s}
```

> ```
> 2^p > 832 && 2^r > 2^(8 + p)/(-832 + 2^p) &&
> 2^s > (2^(12 + p) + 2^(12 + p + r))/(-2^(8 + p) - 13 2^(6 + r) + 2^(p + r))
> ```

Instead of putting this output to `Reduce` and getting

> ```
> Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce. >>
> ```

we'll do this :

```
Reduce[2^p > 832, p, Reals]
```

> ```
> p > (6 Log[2] + Log[13])/Log[2]
> ```

or

```
Reduce[2^p > 832, p, Integers]
```

> ```
> p ∈ Integers && p >= 10
> ```

```
(6 Log[2] + Log[13])/Log[2] // N
```

> ```
> 9.70044
> ```

Next e.g. we can find bounds for `r` and `s` assuming values of `p` :

```
Reduce[p == # && 2^r > 2^(8 + p)/(-832 + 2^p) && 
       2^s > (2^(12 + p) + 2^(12 + p + r))/(-2^(8 + p) - 13 2^(6 + r) + 2^(p + r)),   
       {r, s}, Reals] & /@ Range[10, 13]
```

[image]

If we assume the domain of `r ,s` to be `Integers` that will lead to this message `Reduce::nsmet: ...`.

```
RegionPlot3D[ineq, {p, 8, 15}, {r, 8, 15}, {s, 11, 15}, Mesh -> 4, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, 
             PlotStyle -> Directive[ Specularity[0.3], Opacity[0.3], FaceForm[ Blue, Green]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried your hand at [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/)?  I think you'd be good at it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, once I took a look at PE, but somehow I haven't so far returned there.

Comment: @Artes: That substitution $2^p \rightarrow x, 2^r \rightarrow y, 2^s \rightarrow z$ was a great idea. Thanks for the answer!